# Plone4 - Installing addons

Tags: plone

I am new to Plone and I am having trouble understanding how to install addons. I have read the documentation provided on their site, but I am still a bit confused.

The addon that I am trying to install is http://plone.org/products/uwosh.timeslot.

In the documentation, I see them using a something like cmd.exe, but I am not really sure what it is. Is it the python.exe located in the python folder?

Also, I am not clear if the addon that I wish to install is in an "egg" form.

Could someone please provide me with a detailed process for installation?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your feedback. I have updated http://plone.org/documentation/kb/installing-add-ons-quick-how-to to reflect changes suggested in this discussion to make Plone add-on installation little easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/installing-add-ons-quick-how-to

1. Find, then edit your buildout.cfg file per instructions above to add the uwosh.timeslot egg.
2. Re-run bin/buildout (or bin\buildout on windows) from the main plone directory on the command-line (do not run from the bin directory as your current working directory).

Answering your other questions:

- Yes, packages listed on PyPI.python.org are "eggs" in the sense that you install them as eggs in buildout, not classic "Products".
- cmd.exe is MS Windows command-line, assuming you are using Windows, not Unix.

  - This is only useful if you know where your Plone installation is located on disk -- you should.

Comment: See also http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Good-tutorials-for-Windows-and-UNIX-command-lines-tp7272259.html - we need to be able to redirect the users to cmdline basics tutorial if they lack necessary skills beforehand